# How to analytically derive the equation of the amplitude of the force being transmitted to the ground of a damped, forced vibration system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, vibrations

For this question, I really have tried to produce some working but the entire thing is just deeply confusing me.

[image]

I know my equations for the displacement of this mass will be as follows:

[image: insert second image]

I have successfully derived these equations from the freebody diagram of the mass, and understand where these equations come from. However, when it comes to determining the force being applied to the ground from these equations, I have no clue. How would I go about doing this, as I am completely lost.
I was previously under the assumption that Xf was simply the force being transmitted to the ground, but surely that can't possible be the case.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground force is the sum of the spring and dashpot forces

$$ F_{\rm ground} = k x  + c \dot{x} $$

The is because the spring and damper are just force members (equal and opposite forces on their ends) since they are assumed massless.

This means the free body diagram should yield the following

$$ P(t) - F_{\rm ground} = m \ddot{x} $$

which you use to find a solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, as I have put up previously in the 2nd image, for a damped forced vibration, the solution for x(t) is quite a long one, and hence so will x'(t). So, in my mind, the most straightforward way of calculating Fground would simply be multiplying these 2 very long derivations by k and x respectively. Is this how it should be done, as that seems too complex, and from there I cannot see how I would obtain the amplitude either. Could you please explain how it could be done? Thanks.

Comment: Because the solution is _too long_ for you does not mean it is not  solution. There are simplifications you can do, as you can collect all the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms for a result of the form $$F_{\rm ground} = \exp(-\beta t) \left( A \sin \omega t + B \sin \omega t \right)$$